# Unable to delete object array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, instance

Hi I have a problem with deleting an object array.
Whenever I start my code, it works just fine, but when I close,
I am getting the error: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
The code goes like this:

I initialize an instance of an object and immediately make an empty array out of it.

```
Class* classObject[15];
```

Afterwards, I define the empty array in a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  classObject[i] = new Class();
}
```

When the application closes, the following code should delete the array out of memory.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  delete classObject[i];
}
```

Instead of successfully closing, I am getting the Access violation error.
How can I fix this problem and where? 
Also, are there maybe other ways I could create objects in a for loop?

Comment: Have you perhaps already free'd those pointers? Or set them to `NULL` or otherwise changed the pointers? Use of smart pointers (such as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) _might_ have mitigated this problem.

Comment: For such problems it is best if you can provide a complete example that demonstrates the behavior. See http://sscce.org

Comment: You've probably corrupted the free space arena with some earlier operation.  Another possibility is that you're doing something bad in the destructor of `Class`.

Comment: If you solved the problem, post an answer and accept it. Answers do not go in questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A
{
    public:
        A():a(0){};
    private:
        int a;
};

int main()
{
    A* arr[15];

    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new A();
    }
    for(int i =0;i<15;i++)
    {
        delete arr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is no any error in my code .Have you delete the point before?